# How to predict a univariate time series with Elman neural networks in R

Tags: r

I have following time series on weekly basis

```
    Week      Value
    1         23456
    2         56787
    3         12546
    4         5564
```

Like wise I have data for 4 years.  I want to use Elman neural networks to predict the non-linear time series. I am facing the difficulty in data preparation for the following elman function.

```
elman(x, y, size = c(5), maxit = 100,
     initFunc = "JE_Weights", initFuncParams = c(1, -1, 0.3, 1, 0.5),
     learnFunc = "JE_BP", learnFuncParams = c(0.2), updateFunc = "JE_Order",
     updateFuncParams = c(0), shufflePatterns = FALSE, linOut = TRUE,
     outContext = FALSE, inputsTest = NULL, targetsTest = NULL, ...)
```

What should be the value of `X` and `Y` ? And while predicting for weeks ahead,how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with `elman`, but I assume that `x` contains explanatory variables and `y` contains the data you want to forecast. This, at least, is standard in R.

For predicting, there is probably a `predict.elman` function, to which you will need to feed the values of the explanatory variable `x`. This is frequently a `newdata` parameter.

The help pages or any package vignettes should be helpful.